# how to change font family of urdu characters in a textbox

Tags: c#, jquery, css

I am using jquery to convert the english characters to urdu characters in a text box (asp: server side control ). Now i want to change the font family of these urdu characters. Is there any way or any library, having a collection of font families, to change the font family?

Comment: What have you tried? I'd just use the CSS property of the text box to specify the new font family but im not clear what you want to trigger this, possibly document ready event?

Comment: Thanks dam but am looking for a way through which i can select any font-family of urdu language and apply to my text box. eg: i want collection of font families, through which i can choose any one of them and apply to my text box. Do you know the names of Professional looking font families that i can apply?

Comment: http://font.urduweb.org/

Answer (score 0):

Please use inline CSS in your div,span,p or any tag in :

**for HTML:**

```
  <input style="font-family:Georgia, Serif" value="اڈوبی عریبک بولڈ"/>
```

**for asp:**

```
<asp:textbox id = Textbox1 runat ="server" style="font-family:Georgia, Serif" />
```

instead of ***Georgia, Serif*** use your font-family

Comment: ok deepak its good but is there any way or library having a collection of urdu font families through which i can select any font family and apply to my text box?

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#yourTextboxId").css("font-family", "newFontname");
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code for that font-family:

http://cdn.urdupoint.com/daily/font-styles/nafees_web_naskhshipped.eot

Now, you can use: @font-face to apply this to use own website.

You should have seen this code in the website's HTML Inspector. It was just there at the end of the code.

For @font-face: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@font-face

Comment: HTML:   <style>@font-face { font-family: myFirstFont; src: url(nafees_web_naskhshipped.eot); } div { font-family:myFirstFont; } </style> </head> <body> <div> وہ ہر چند چاہیں گے کہ آگ سے نکل جائیں مگر اس سے نہیں نکل سکیں گے اور ان کیلئے ہمیشہ کا عذاب ہے۔ اور چوری کرنے والا مرد اور چوری کرنے والی عورت ان کا ایک ایک ہاتھ کاٹ دو ، یہ ان کے کرتوتوں کی سزا اور اللہ کی طرف سے عبرت کے طور پر ہے اور اللہ زبردست ہے صاحب حکمت ہے۔ پھر جو شخص گناہ کے بعد توبہ کرلے اور نیکو کار ہو جائے تو اللہ اسکو معاف کردے گا، کچھ شک نہیں کہ اللہ بڑا بخشنے  والا ہے بڑا مہربان ہے۔ </div> </body> </html>